# custom post type to post association in wordpress

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

I have created a custom post type called groups which is now available in the dashboard of the admin console on WordPress. I now want to be able to add multiple groups to posts. Similar to how one can add tags to posts. I would really appreciate some solutions to how I can go about doing so. thank you in advance.

Comment: You should use taxonomy to associate posts. CPTS was not designed to be used this way. Or create custom tables.

Comment: I want to able to add these groups to the posts. Is that not possible?

Comment: Anything is possible since WordPress is just php and mysql database. But the question is, do you have enough knowledge and time to undertake things that are this far from standard way of doing things? Why not just use taxonomy, since this is what you will be using your groups for anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a plugin which does exactly what I asked for and it is very simple to use. https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts